# Find a given value and return the key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would like to find a given value and return the key, Ive tried many ways of solving this but none work.
I spent many hours testing diffrent solutions but no luck so far, yet this is such a simple task.
Here are some functions that I have tried but none return the correct key: (in this case should be 0)

This returns nothing:

```
 $mapkey = $data['srv']['map_image'];
 $ikey = array_search($mapkey, $data['srv']['maps']);
 if ($ikey !== FALSE) {
 // Match made.
 }
```

I get '3' when it should be '0', from this one:

```
foreach ($data['srv']['maps'] as $key => $value) {
$mapkey = ($data['srv']['map_image']);
    if ($value === $mapkey && $data['srv']['maps'][$key]['map_image'] === $mapkey) {
return $key;
}
}
```

I get nothing from this and should be '0':

```
$mapkey = $data['srv']['map_image'];

foreach ($data['srv']['maps'] as $key => $val) {
if ($val === $mapkey) {
return $key;
}
}
```

This one completely crashes the web page:

```
function recursive_array_search($mapkey,$data) {
    foreach($data['srv']['maps'] as $key=>$val) {
$mapkey = $data['srv']['map_image'];
    $imagekey=$key;
    if($mapkey===$val OR (is_array($val) && recursive_array_search($mapkey,$val) !== false)) {
return $imagekey;
        }
}
return false;
}
```

Example of the $data array:

```
Array
(
[srv] => Array
    (
        [map_name] => map 1 
        [map_image] => MP_001
        [maps] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [map_name] => map 1 
                        [map_image] => mp_001
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [map_name] => map 2
                        [map_image] => mp_017
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [map_name] => map 3
                        [map_image] => mp_014
                    )
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [map_name] => map 4
                        [map_image] => mp_007
                 )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: The fourth one seems that you are totally confussed..

Comment: Hi the only problem with the forth one is that I copied and pasted straight from the php manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)  ....  Its rated the top answer ??

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, you are searching directly inside the `$data['srv']['maps']` which contains keys like 0 , 1 . But you have to search inside all the 0 , 1s so it fails.

In second one, if you remove the first condition it shall work. Bcoz in first condition you are comparing a value with an array (`$value`) is an array.

The above mistake you are doing in third also.

Fourth is too complicated. Best thing is thata you remove the first condition from second one.

Update: As per your update, for comparison they shall be in same case ;-)

Comment: Hi Darshan Jain unfortunately even with the first condition removed it still returns '4'. I think it has something to do with the $key '0' it fails when a key is 0.

Comment: I dont think it should have happened . Are u pasting ur exact code @Renny

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have come up with a solution.

```
foreach ($data['srv']['maps'] as $key => $value) {  
$mapkey = strtolower($data['srv']['map_image']);
   if ($mapkey == $data['srv']['maps'][$key]['map_image']) {
       $imgkey = $key;
   }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($imgkey);
echo '</pre>';
```

Returns '0'

The problem I had was where the code was being placed and the fact I couldn't have $key returned as it broke the rest of the code.

Comment: Is it that both `$data['srv']['map_image']` and that inside `$data['srv']['maps'][0]['map_image']` are of different case ?

Comment: Can u remove `strtolower()` and tell what happens ?

Comment: Hi my bad the example above should have been MP_001 so strtolower needs to be included for an exact match.

Comment: Lol . Thats why it wasnt working. If you have understood then accept urs/ mine answer